# How to make vertically expanding cards in CSS?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have recently started learning web development and wanted to make a project by myself. I learnt to make a cool desktop site but am not being able to understand how to convert the horizontal cards, vertical.

[This is the homepage](https://ruchirich.github.io/God-of-War/)

I just wanted all the panels to stack in a column and expand vertically in smartphones. I did try to use media query and the changed flex direction to column but it ended up like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frnsw.png).

```js
  
const panels = document.querySelectorAll(".panel");

panels.forEach((panels) => {
    panels.addEventListener("click", () => {
        removeActiceClasses();
        panels.classList.add("active");
    });

});

function removeActiceClasses() {
    panels.forEach((panels) => {
        panels.classList.remove("active");
    
    });

}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli&display=swap');
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    background-color: #1a1a2e;
    font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
}
.container {
    display: flex;
    width: 90vw;
}
.panel {
    background-size: auto 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 80vh;
    border-radius: 50px;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    flex: 0.5;
    margin: 10px;
    position: relative;
    transition: flex 0.7s ease-in;
}
.panel h3 {
    font-size: 24px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}
.panel.active {
    flex: 5;
}
.panel.active h3 {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in 0.4s;
}
@media(max-width: 480px) {
    .container {
        width: 90vw;
    }
    .panel:nth-of-type(4),
    .panel:nth-of-type(5) {
        display: none;
    }
    .abilities {
        background-position: right;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />

      <title>God of War</title>
      <link rel="icon" href="favicon/favicon.ico" type="image/icon">
  </head>

  <body>
      <div class="container">
          <div class="panel world active" style="background-image: url(images/God-of-war-world.jpg);">
              <h3>Explore The World</h3>

          </div>
          <div class="panel characyers" style="background-image: url(images/God-of-War-characters.jpeg);">
              <h3>Main Characters</h3>

          </div>
          <div class="panel creatures" style="background-image: url(images/God-of-War-creatures.jpg);">
              <h3>Mythical Creatures</h3>

          </div>
          <div class="panel enemies" style="background-image: url(images/God-of-War-enemies.jpg);">
              <h3>Enemies</h3>

          </div>
          <div class="panel abilities" style="background-image: url(images/God-of-War-abilities.jpg);">
              <h3>Items and Abilities</h3>

          </div>
      </div>

      <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you include your js file?

Comment: Hey! First of all, make sure that you always close your HTML tags. I saw in your HTML file that you didn't close your <head> tag

Comment: @Ava i have added the entire snippet

Comment: @Qontrol oh damn i hadnt noticed it, i have made the changes, Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

You can just add `flex-direction: column` to the container and give it a height for example as per your usage of view port units - `100vh`. As you are making use of the view port units, seeing the output in full screen would be better.

```js
const panels = document.querySelectorAll(".panel");

panels.forEach((panels) => {
    panels.addEventListener("click", () => {
        removeActiceClasses();
        panels.classList.add("active");
    });

});

function removeActiceClasses() {
    panels.forEach((panels) => {
        panels.classList.remove("active");
    
    });

}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli&display=swap');
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    background-color: #1a1a2e;
    font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
}
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; /* Code added */
    width: 90vw;
    height: 100vh; /* Code added */
}
.panel {
    background-size: auto 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 80vh;
    border-radius: 50px;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    flex: 0.5;
    margin: 10px;
    position: relative;
    transition: flex 0.7s ease-in;
}
.panel h3 {
    font-size: 24px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}
.panel.active {
    flex: 2;
}
.panel.active h3 {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in 0.4s;
}
@media(max-width: 480px) {
    .container {
        width: 90vw;
    }
    .panel:nth-of-type(4),
    .panel:nth-of-type(5) {
        display: none;
    }
    .abilities {
        background-position: right;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />

      <title>God of War</title>
      <link rel="icon" href="favicon/favicon.ico" type="image/icon">
  </head>

  <body>
      <div class="container">
          <div class="panel world active" style="background-image: url(https://oyster.ignimgs.com/wordpress/stg.ign.com/2020/03/god-of-war-fallen-god-cover-1211969.jpg);">
              <h3>Explore The World</h3>

          </div>
          <div class="panel characyers" style="background-image: url(https://oyster.ignimgs.com/wordpress/stg.ign.com/2020/03/god-of-war-fallen-god-cover-1211969.jpg);">
              <h3>Main Characters</h3>

          </div>
          <div class="panel creatures" style="background-image: url(https://oyster.ignimgs.com/wordpress/stg.ign.com/2020/03/god-of-war-fallen-god-cover-1211969.jpg);">
              <h3>Mythical Creatures</h3>

          </div>
          <div class="panel enemies" style="background-image: url(https://oyster.ignimgs.com/wordpress/stg.ign.com/2020/03/god-of-war-fallen-god-cover-1211969.jpg);">
              <h3>Enemies</h3>

          </div>
          <div class="panel abilities" style="background-image: url(https://oyster.ignimgs.com/wordpress/stg.ign.com/2020/03/god-of-war-fallen-god-cover-1211969.jpg);">
              <h3>Items and Abilities</h3>

          </div>
      </div>

      <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! i finally did it